# Observe livedata in viewmodel to update UI through property binding

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I would like to observe a `currentUser: LiveData<User>` property (exposed by a `UserRepository`) within the `ProfileViewModel` to update a `user: User` property. This property is bound to the UI through databinding and should update the UI in case of a change. This is my assumption.

I tried to set the `user`property with Transformations but it doesn't worked.

Some code? 
`DatabaseService.kt`

```
    fun getById(documentId: String): MutableLiveData<T> {
        val resultObj = MutableLiveData<T>()
        db.collection(className)
            .document(documentId)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val obj = task.result?.toObject(modelClass)
                    resultObj.value = obj
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, task.exception?.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        return resultObj;
    }
```

`UserRepository.kt`

```
   fun getCurrentUser(): LiveData<User> {
        return this.getById(FirebaseAuthService.userUid)
    }
```

`ProfileViewModel.kt`

```
    // This doesn't work.
    val userRep = UserRepository();
    var user: User = User()

    init {
        Transformations.map(userRep.getCurrentUser()) { firebaseUser ->
            user = firebaseUser;
        }
    }
```

The `user: User` property is bound to UI. How can I update this propery with the value from livedata object. I don't want to observe `userRep.getCurrentUser()`in fragment and hold a reference to UI component and update in case of a change.

Comment: I suspect issue is that you need to call `binding.setLifecycleOwner()` in your fragment (see example in https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-data-binding-binding-to-livedata-one-and-two-way-binding-dae1cd68530f)

Comment: Great! I've tried it out and it works thank you! Now I have to understand why it works. :))

Comment: Key aspect of LiveData objects is that they're lifecycle aware (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) so need to typically exist in context of some lifecycle owner

Comment: Great! Thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

The view won't update when the property `user` changes because it won't know that it has changed. Try using a `MutableLiveData<User>`:

`ProfileViewModel.kt`

```
val userRep = UserRepository();
val user = MutableLiveData<User>(User())

init {
    Transformations.map(userRep.getCurrentUser()) { firebaseUser ->
        user.postValue(firebaseUser);
    }
}
```

Doing this, the view will update because the `LiveData` used in the `user` property will notify its changes to it.

Comment: Thats what I've done now like `var user: LiveData<User> = userRep.getCurrentUser()` This also doesn't worked untill I set `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` thanks to @John O'Reilly answer.

Comment: Oh, I wrongly assumed you would be doing that already. Glad to see you solved it!